# getting quarterly rows from partially aggregated yearly data

Tags: sqlite

I have a table that looks like

```
account  |  date       | value
1.11     | 2014-03-31  | 10
1.11     | 2014-06-30  | 20
1.11     | 2014-09-30  | 30
1.11     | 2014-12-31  | 100
1.21     | 2014-03-31  | 15
1.21     | 2014-06-30  | 20
1.21     | 2014-09-30  | 35
1.21     | 2014-12-31  | 90
1.11     | 2015-03-31  | 10
1.11     | 2015-06-30  | 20
1.11     | 2015-09-30  | 30
1.11     | 2015-12-31  | 100
```

The value column in xxxx-12-31 is the yearly total. I'd like to obtain a table that looks like

```
account  |  date       | value
1.11     | 2014-03-31  | 10
1.11     | 2014-06-30  | 20
1.11     | 2014-09-30  | 30
1.11     | 2014-12-31  | 40
1.21     | 2014-03-31  | 15
1.21     | 2014-06-30  | 20
1.21     | 2014-09-30  | 35
1.21     | 2014-12-31  | 20
1.11     | 2015-03-31  | 10
1.11     | 2015-06-30  | 20
1.11     | 2015-09-30  | 30
1.11     | 2015-12-31  | 40
```

Where the rows at xxxx-12-31 now have the quarterly data. Incidentally how would it be possible to obtain the data only for the 2014 4th quarter?, namely something like

```
1.11     | 2014-12-31  | 40
1.21     | 2014-12-31  | 20
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When the date ends with `-12-31`, subtract the sum of the other values in the same year:

```
SELECT account
       date,
       CASE WHEN date NOT LIKE '%-12-31'
       THEN value
       ELSE value - (SELECT SUM(value)
                     FROM MyTable AS T2
                     WHERE strftime('%Y', T2.date) = strftime('%Y', MyTable.date)
                       AND T2.date < MyTable.date)
       END AS value
FROM MyTable;
```